# jqGrid not loading data on scroll (Internet Explorer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, jqgrid

I am having an issue that is very similar to the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374716/jqgrid-not-loading-data-on-scroll.

JQgrid's 'populateVisible' function is never executing the grid's populate method (maybe it doesn't think that the items to populate are 'visible' because of some IE inconsistency).

I'll paste a snippet of the function below for some context:

```
populateVisible: function() {
            var dh = $(grid.bDiv).height();
            var table = $("table:first", grid.bDiv);
   ....
            var tbot = ttop + table.height();
   ....

            var page, npage, empty;
            if ( tbot < dh && ttop <= 0 &&
                (p.lastpage===undefined||parseInt((tbot + scrollTop + div - 1) / div,10) <= p.lastpage))
            {
                npage = parseInt((dh - tbot + div - 1) / div,10);
                if (tbot >= 0 || npage < 2 || p.scroll === true) {
                    page = Math.round((tbot + scrollTop) / div) + 1;
                    ttop = -1;
                } else {
                    ttop = 1;
                }
            }
    ....
            if (npage) {
                if (p.lastpage && page > p.lastpage || p.lastpage==1 || (page === p.page && page===p.lastpage) ) {
                    return;
                }
                if (grid.hDiv.loading) {
                    grid.timer = setTimeout(grid.populateVisible, p.scrollTimeout);
                } else {
                    p.page = page;
                    if (empty) {
                        grid.selectionPreserver(table[0]);
                        grid.emptyRows.call(table[0], false, false);                                
                    }
                    grid.populate(npage);
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that "tbot < dh" evaluates to false since both equal 562. I'm wondering why these are equal in IE. It seems like IE thinks that the bottom of the table is always the size of the table Div (562). How can I solve this problem and get the code that sets npage and page to execute in IE?

It seems to work fine in Chrome since tbot = 541 and dh = 562.

Since npage is never set, it cannot execute the piece of code that contains 'grid.populate()'.

Does anyone have any input on this problem?

Edit: Removed a lot of code that is unnecessary for the context of the question. See here for entire function: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L948

Comment: You are providing quite a bit of code. It's a lot easier for us the help you with a more reduced test case.

Comment: Thanks Anton for looking. I removed a lot of the code that isn't necessary for the question. Full context can be seen here: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L948